# Надо синонимизировать метки [почта] и [email]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки

- [почта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b0) (164 вопроса)
- [email](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) (862 вопроса)

Основная, мне кажется - [email](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email), т. к. у неё более полное описание, и в ~пять раз больше вопросов.

Comment: Не согласен. Почта — это может быть программа, а e-mail — это всегда адрес электронной почты.

Comment: @Глеб что это за программа такая - "почта"?

Comment: @Эникейщик, в современном компьютерном жаргоне почта — это сокращение от "почтовая программа".

Comment: @Глеб ну если это "современный" компьютерный жаргон из конца 1990-х, то да.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а как сейчас называют почтовые программы? Разве не так же? Говорят же вроде "загляну на почту"? Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: @Глеб в моем окружении так и называют - имейл. И даже если называть "почта", то "загляну В почту", а не "на почту". "На почту" это про Почту России :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 144 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 164 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 119 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'почта': [почта] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 981
tag remapping of [email] and [почта] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
9 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym почта -> email was approved!
```